# Gradle error while importing project from github

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

i am installed android studio 3.4 version and gradle version 5.1

i got following error while importing project from github https://github.com/AkashBang/NavigationView

`Support for builds using Gradle older than 2.6 was deprecated and will be removed in 5.0. You are currently using Gradle version 2.4. You should upgrade your Gradle build to use Gradle 2.6 or later.
ERROR: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip'.`

how can clear this error

Answer (score 1):

Modify file 'gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties' as

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-all.zip
```